# document.getElementById gives me undefined even after window.onload

Tags: javascript

I am trying to simply popup an alert message when a button is clicked.

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("search-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
        alert(document.getElementById("input-text").value)
    })
};
```

This is what I have in my script and below is the HTML

```
    <div class="row" style="
            margin-top: 1.5em;
            margin-bottom: 1.5em;">
        <div class="input-group" style="width: 50%; float: none; margin: 0 auto">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="input-text" />
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button id="search-button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

What I am trying to do is alert the text that I type inside the `input` element.  I thought the issue could be solved by putting inside the `window.onload` but it's still the same.

Any help?

Comment: Works for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4sfdwt2z/. Any errors in your console?

Comment: I suppose you don't want to place your JS code juste before the `</body>`, even if this way garantie better loading performance, so why ?

Comment: window.onloand is not written in some other async function right? Sometimes the handler is attached after window is loaded. Can u check it is written at top level?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, but as an alternate approach you can try it using the [IIFE way](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/https-medium-com-javascript-in-plain-english-stop-feeling-iffy-about-using-an-iife-7b0292aba174)

```js
(function() {
  document.getElementById("search-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert(document.getElementById("input-text").value)
  });
})();
```

```html
<div class="row" style="
            margin-top: 1.5em;
            margin-bottom: 1.5em;">
  <div class="input-group" style="width: 50%; float: none; margin: 0 auto">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="input-text" />
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button id="search-button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">Test</span>
                </button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i actually realized that it works in the very first try. How may app works is that, I open up a new window by using `chrome.windows.create`. When the new window is opened, the button doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You could also wrap it inside the `DOMContentLoaded` instead of using the window.onload event, another script could override your function.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    document.getElementById("search-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
        alert(document.getElementById("input-text").value)
    })
});
```